# what's the best practice for Android application preference's User interface?

Tags: iphone, android

Hi I want to port my iPhone app to Android.
in Iphone the Settings provide a unified UI for application preferences. 
I have read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html about SharedPreferences, but there is no UI
What should I do in Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but there is no UI

Sure there is. It is called a [`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html). You define it using a preference XML resource. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Simple) showing a simple case for this.

Comment: Mark when are you going to update your Tutorials on Preferences? :-) *This method is deprecated.
This function is not relevant for a modern fragment-based PreferenceActivity.* I'd be very interested to see what they've replaced it with. I assume its deprecated in 3.0 onwards

Comment: @Blundell: [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](http://commonsware.com/Android) covers the new preference mechanism. It is not backwards-compatible, so [Android Programming Tutorials](http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials) will be sticking with the original mechanism for the time being.

Comment: I have BC2AD unfortunately my *2nd edition* paperback doesn't update automatically :-) Interesting that it's not backwards compatible. Guess don't have to worry about it then unless your writing an app with minSDKVersion 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Look up `PreferenceActivity`. It allows you create a UI very quickly using XML that matches the general preference look and feel of Android.